# Как найти наименьшее число, большее n, которое кратно m?

Tags: python, алгоритм, оптимизация, арифметика

Пусть есть числа *n* и *m*. Необходимо найти такое наименьшее *k*, что *k > n* и *k % m == 0*.
Есть эффективное решение для *m == 2**p*: `k = (n + m) & ~(m-1)`
Какое есть эффективное решение для других *m*? На ум приходит только: `k = n - (n % m) + m` и `k = m * ((n // m) + 1)`. Но мне оба эти варианта не нравятся, думаю, что можно это реализовать лучше.

Comment: Аналог второго варианта `k = ((n + m) // m) * m`.  Чем же они все плохи?

Comment: @MBo Мне они не нравятся операциями деления и умножения. Я догадываюсь, что первый вариант эффективнее второго и эффективнее нельзя. но, может быть, умные люди что-то подскажут.

Comment: Я бы еще понял, если бы это казалось неэффективным где-нибудь в ассемблере... Но в Python? Что вы сэкономите на этих спичках?

Comment: @Harry Это псевдокод на питоне для понимания. Реализую я это как раз-таки на ассемблере.

Comment: Опять же - вы уже твердо знаете (выполнив замеры), что именно эта часть является узким местом вашей программы?

Comment: @Harry Этот вопрос имеет больше теоретическое значение, чем практическое. Я хочу узнать для себя эффективнейший способ подобного вычисления, как когда-то узнал его для `m == 2**p`, например.

Comment: Тогда - раз практика не волнует - поиск в таблице :) А реально - ну нет другого варианта в общем случае... Я прикинул - если числа уже в регистрах, то 4 команд с головой... Да, `div` и `mul`, но это очень быстро :)

Comment: Есть реализация деления через умножение и сдвиг, но для каждого m свои параметры нужны.